# Calculating $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1*2+2*3+...+n(n+1)}{1*3+3*5+...+(2n-1)(2n+1)} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

This might seem pretty straightforward, as both the numerator and the denominator seem to resemble some well-known sums, however the numerator is the only one which can actually be rewritten as $\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}$. Could you point me to the right direction as to how I'd be able to continue the exercise in this manner, or is there perhaps a different way of dealing with this limit?

Comment: note that $(2k-1)(2k+1)=(2k)^2-1$

Comment: Cesaro stolz theorem

Comment: assuming terms in numerator (and denominator) are being summed?

Comment: @Milan That's the best answer; you should write one up.

Comment: @Milan Thanks! I tried this one as well and I got to the end of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method one**

We can write the summation formula for both the numerator and denominator which is not my favorite :)

**Method two**

We use calculus (and the definition of integral) to find the limit.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1*2+2*3+...+n(n+1)}{1*3+3*5+...+(2n-1)(2n+1)}
{=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^ni(i+1)}{\sum_{i=1}^n4i^2-1}
\\=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^ni^2+\sum_{i=1}^ni}{-n+\sum_{i=1}^n4i^2}
\\=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{{1\over n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left({i\over n}\right)^2+{1\over n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\left({i\over n}\right)}{-{1\over n^2}+{1\over n}\sum_{i=1}^n4\left({i\over n}\right)^2}
\\=
\frac{\int_0^1 x^2dx}{\int_0^1 4x^2dx}
\\={1\over 4}
}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: note that the bottom sum is

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n(2i-1)(2i+1) = \sum_{i=1}^n(4i^2 - 1). 
$$

From here you might be interested in the [sum of square integers formula.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assign the series as $a_n$. Notice, that:

$$b_n = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i (i+1)}{\sum_{i=1}^n (2i - 2) 2i}=
\frac{1}{4} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i (i+1)}{\sum_{i=1}^n (i - 1) 2i}<a_n<
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i (i+1)}{\sum_{i=1}^n 2i \cdot 2i} = 
\frac{1}{4}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i (i+1)}{\sum_{i=1}^n i^2} = c_n$$

Also $b_n \to \frac{1}{4}$ and $c_n \to \frac{1}{4}$. Using squeze theorem we get $a_n \to \frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dirty and rough way of looking at the limit:

$(2n-1)(2n+1)\approx4\cdot n(n+1)$.

Therefore, for large $n$, the denominator is approximately $4$ times the numerator, which means the limit is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{4}$.